# Laurent series $f(z)=\frac{z}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2z-2})}$ in $z=2$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

How to develop in Laurent series the following function in $z=2$

$$f(z)= \frac{z}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2z-2})}$$
My problem is that I can not develop

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2z-2})}$$

Thank you everybody

Comment: Let $u=z-2$ and develop $f(u)$ around $0$

Comment: Do you know Bernoulli's numbers ?

Comment: Use $$
\frac{1}{\sin z}=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{z}{6}+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{2(2^{2n-1}-1)B_{2n}}{(2n)!}z^{2n-1}+\cdots,\quad|z|<\pi,$$
where $B_{2n}$ are Bernoulli's numbers.